# What are some techniques/methods that you would suggest for an online tandem learning relation to work?

Tags: language-exchange

I got to know this guy from the Internet, I'm a Vietnamese living in Germany and learning German; he is a German living in Vietnam and learning Vietnamese. I really want this tandem learning thing to work out for us because, from my side, I want to improve my German skills so much.

I've read some tips for how to make the most of a tandem partnership, but very few of them deals with solely cyber partnership. We obviously won't get to meet in person anytime soon. Therefore, I would like to hear some suggestions as to how to make this situation work out well for both of us?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you find some common interests with your learning partner so you can learn and enjoy your conversations at the same (this will encourage you both to continue this tandem learning relationship). Be kind and funny, offer your help to him and ask him to help you when you can’t understand something. Also, you can suggest you communicate in German one day, and in Vietnamese the other day so you can both practice the language you are learning. Finally, even if you won't get to meet in person in the near future, at some point you can try to videocall each other from time to time.